# Add rnorm during dplyr pipeline but when setting the sd set it by groups

Tags: r

A dataframe:

```
mydf <- data.frame(
  x = rep(letters[1:3], 4),
  y = rnorm(12, 0, 3)
)
```

I can easily mutate a new column z that is the value of y plus or minus a random number:

```
mydf <- mydf %>% 
  mutate(z = rnorm(nrow(.), mean = 0, sd = sd(y)))
```

What I wouldlike to do is create z as a random number but when setting the sd use the sd for that letter only.

Tried:

```
mydf <- mydf %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  mutate(z = rnorm(nrow(.), mean = 0, sd = sd(y)))
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `z`.
x Input `z` can't be recycled to size 4.
ℹ Input `z` is `rnorm(nrow(.), mean = 0, sd = sd(y))`.
ℹ Input `z` must be size 4 or 1, not 12.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: x = "a".
```

How can I add z, which is the value of y plus or minus a random number with an sd equal to that of the sd for the group as opposed to the column as a whole?

Comment: Instead of nrow(.) Does just putting 1 for n in the rnorm call work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the `nrow(.)` will break the group by attribute and get the entire row and `mutate` requires the `length` of the new the column to be the same as the number of rows of the earlier data.  So, this will break that stream unless we wrap the column in a `list` which may not be what the OP wanted.

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>% 
   group_by(x) %>% 
   summarise(n = nrow(.))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  x         n
#  <chr> <int>
#1 a        12 ###
#2 b        12 ###
#3 c        12 ###
```

We can use `n()`

```
mydf %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
   mutate(z = rnorm(n(), mean = 0, sd = sd(y)))
```